# How can I fix NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException

Tags: ios, xcode, exception, ios5, xcode4.3

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (NSLayoutConstraint)'

I have a very simple app

One view has one button

I Control Click and dragged the button to a second view and selected MODAL

When I run it in the simulator, everything works

When i run it in my iPad running iOS 5.1.1, it crashes with the error above. I have no idea why and there is no code.

Comment: Refer to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198981/presentviewcontroller-crash][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198981/presentviewcontroller-crash

Answer (score 79, accepted):

This is occuring because you are using Xcode 4.5 (or previously the beta) which uses "auto layout" by default. Auto layout is only available on iOS 6 so you will get a runtime error on previous iOS versions.

You can fix this by opening your Storyboard, opening the Utilities pane, and disabling the "Use Autolayout" checkbox in the first tab/section:

[image]

For regular non-storyboard nibs, select the top-level view to access this option.

Comment: Thanks. I would never have found this.

Comment: @Jignesh: This is a well upvoted answer already, and your edit serves better as a comment (or even an answer in it self)I'll instead add your edit text as a comment to the answer.

Comment: From Jignesh's edit *"When I solved my problem I had to uncheck `Use Autolayout` on `nib file` that caused problem for me"*: "You can fix this by opening your Storyboard or any nib file that is causing problem, opening the Utilities pane, and disabling the "Use Autolayout" checkbox in the first tab/section"

Comment: My iOS deployment target is 4.3 and I used Autolayout for some views but xcode didn't warn me about this at all. We shouldn't even be able to build an app that has such settings! Thank you apple...

Comment: Well, technically you may have an autolayout view which is only used on iOS 6 and later. So it is a legitimate use case to have autolayout enabled even with a deployment target of < 6.0

Comment: Okay, I did as mentioned in Answer and now the error is solved but I have a search bar in a view controller which is positioned on top, but when I run the app the search bar is at the bottom of view :\. What now? Please help.

Answer (score 5):

In Your Xib-> Identity and type ->Interface Builder Document -> uncheck useAutoLayout check box,this is the new feature with Ios6