# Xib for different iOS devices/simulator?

Tags: ios, xib

I run the simulator, I go to Hardware and Device, it shows list of Devices

```
iOS Simulator > Hardware > Device


iPad
iPad (Retina)

iPhone
iPhone (Retina 3.5 inch)
iPhone (Retina 4 inch)
```

I want to make different XIBs for all these devices. But I want to know the way. as I see there are two options in Xib Attribute Inspector

```
Xib Attribute Inspector > Size

Freeform
Retina 3.5 Full Screen
Retina 4 Full Screen
```

Though there

```
iPhone/iPod Touch 320x480
iPhone/iPod Touch having retina display 640x960
iPhone/iPod touch 5th 640x1136
iPad with non retina display 768x1024
iPad With retina display 1536x2048
iPad mini 768x1024
```

`
How should I handle Xibs for above given Devices shown in simulator and how it covers all the iOS devices?

Comment: why don't you try to use autoresize

Comment: Autosize option for what dear? @Herçules

Comment: Autoresizing for 640x960 and 640x1136 you can made different xibs for iPad and iPhone.No need to made different xib for retina display.

Comment: so, How will I handle for images of Xib Ratina Display? I have iPhone and iPhone ratina, so there will be two types of images and sizes, so how will I use these images without ratina xib?

Comment: I think you are talking about option of User AutoLayout, but I really don't like it, it does not work completely on programmer positions,

Comment: No I am talking about autoresizing

Comment: But, If I will set image imageName.png in xib, so where I will use imageName@2x.png,

Comment: image for simple size should be named as image.png and image for retina should be named as image.@2x.png.You have to keep two images in your project

Comment: The OS will automatically pick the right image.

Comment: means I have to make two Xibs only ? and put image of all sizes with correct names in resources, and it will pick respective image?

Comment: But iPhone 5 is having larger screen then that of iPhone 4, so I have to two xibs, is it right? (DON"T want to use AutoLayout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get right tutorial for autoresizing [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_5_iPhone_Rotation,_View_Resizing_and_Layout_Handling).

Just keep only two xib's

1) For iPhone that should be of size 320x480(3.5) OR 320x568 (4.0)
2)For iPad that should be of size 768x1024.

Manage Images for iphone and ipad with the same name differentiating it with prefix before extension.

like

image.png for iphone
image@2x.png for iphone retina.

Change subViews autoresize as

[image]

Check your 3.5 and 4.0 view as

[image]

Comment: but where is iPhone 5, its even more than 320 x 568 ? so ?

Comment: ok, Let me handle it. But as far as i think, auto size working in Rotation, and resize views dimensions, but for complete iphone 5, i might need an xib

Comment: No need sir , I am also using autoresizing for 3.5 and 4.0 screen size

Comment: Ok Sir, Let me try your Style, but one last comment I want to , May I?

Comment: I made these two xib. Retina 3.5 Full Screen
Retina 4 Full Screen

Comment: No need 2 xib Duaan.Just keep one xib

Comment: One Xib only, but sir iPhone Retina Full Screen height is larger, this is where i am stuck :(

Comment: while making app keep your xib size 3.5 and use autoresize.After that while running in iphone 5 screen.It will automatically adjust by autoresizing.

Comment: And remember, autoresize is **NOT** autolayout. That seems to be the source of confusion here.

Comment: Just try u will soon get success

Comment: yes @BergQuester right autoresizing is totally different from autolayout.I still didn't understand how  to use autolayout.

Answer (score 1):

Create image.png and image@2x.png in your project. When referencing the image, use image.png. The OS will automatically select the correct image for the display.

To handle iPhone 5 vs iPhone 4, use [auto resize, also known as springs and struts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526019/update-storyboard-to-ios-6-with-backwards-compatibility). This is what was used to handle dynamic layouts before autolayout came along.

You should only need two xibs by using these methods, one for iPad and one for iPhone.

Comment: I dont want to use AutoLayout dear

Comment: Springs and struts/autoresize is **NOT** AutoLayout.