# iPad: iOS 6.0 AutoLayout and iOS 5.0 AutoSize together?

Tags: ipad, ios5, ios6, autosize, autolayout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enabling auto layout in iOS 6 while remaining backwards compatible with iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411980/enabling-auto-layout-in-ios-6-while-remaining-backwards-compatible-with-ios-5)

I know that AutoLayout feature supported from iOS 6.0 and if I want to support iOS 5.0, I had to implement manual methods in willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation to resize the controls in portrait and landscap mode. My question is can I have some settings such that when my application runs on iOS 6.0, it uses AutoLayout and when it runs on iOS 5.0, it uses custom methods? I think checking for iOS version before running custom methods should be the solution but I can't have AutoLayout and Autosize option together. Could someone please suggest their thought on this please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have a look at the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411980/enabling-auto-layout-in-ios-6-while-remaining-backwards-compatible-with-ios-5)

Essentially, create 2 deployment targets, each using a different storyboard (one which uses Autolayout, and one which doesn't).