# UIView within a UIView not showing up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, storyboard

I have created a UIView (yellow) in storyboard and then dragged two other UIViews (green and red) by dragging them inside the yellow one. It looks fine in Xcode storyboard.

When I run in the simulator the green and red UIViews don't show up?  The only simulator it works in is when the device is set to iPhone Retina 4. The screen below is iPhone Retina 3.5.

Any ideas on what the issue might be?

[image]

UPDATE: Image to show storyboard structure.

[image]

Comment: make sure that view will be subview's of yellow view.

Comment: It shows in the storyboard document outline that it is.

Comment: are you using AutoLayout?

Comment: Yes. Also if I throw a button inside the green uiview the button shows up but the greet UIView still won't show up.

Comment: no, i mean in your xcode left hand side panel shows view, in that see that red and green view is in the yellow view.

Comment: try without using auto layout..

Comment: I did and things show up, but everything is out of wack. Widths and heights are way to small or to big.

Comment: check autosizing of your red and green view..

Comment: have you checked it in your iPhone simulator? what i see look like iPad

Comment: That is iPhone simulator iphone 3.5 retina.

Comment: ok i just want to confirm @jgervin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok fixed this. The issue is autolayout. I had to setup constraints for the red and green UIViews, such as pin height and pin widths.

Answer (score 1):

You need to resize the views to adjust them for the different heights. Right now, the view is clipped because of `Autolayout` and the red & green buttons are hidden on the upper side.

A very easy way is to use AutoResizing flags from the xib itself! Just click on the individual component(`UIButton`, `UILabel`,etc) and change the flags as you can see below: [image]

Do this programmatically for complex UIs.

Comment: With Autolayout on you don't have these options.

Comment: Again, if you set the simulator to iPhone 4 Retina everything shows up perfectly. I think it has something to do with autolayou/ constraints on old devices.

Comment: `Autolayout` does not work for pre-iOS 6! Check [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411980/enabling-auto-layout-in-ios-6-while-remaining-backwards-compatible-with-ios-5). You wouldn't want to handle it differently for different iOS!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by setting proper corner radius.