# From May 1 - iPhone 5 support - then what is the minimum iOS version appstore supports?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, autolayout, iphone-5

Apple posted in its developer news - 
"starting May 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be buit for iOS devices with Retina display and iPhone apps must also support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5."

Sure we have to use iOS 6 to use autoLayout for supporting iPhone 5 and previous devices ..
But is there any other way ?

If it is so, then what is the minimum iOS version app store will support starting May 1 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to use auto layout to support the iPhone 5.

On May 1st you can still support iOS 4.3 or later. You can still support any device that runs iOS 4.3 or later.

The requirement is that your app must have full retina support (@2x images) and you must support the 4" screen of the iPhone 5 and 5th gen iPod touch (no more letter boxing).

So basically very little is changing. Apple is just requiring people to support newer devices.

Comment: 'no more letter boxing' means then for supporting ios4.3 'two story boards or two xibs, right? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12537643

Comment: I don't know. I don't use storyboards or xibs. I do all of my UIs in code. But I've seen plenty of posts here that discuss the best way to support the two different sized screens. Some searching should find you good answers about the best way to handle that.

Comment: You can use springs and strust combined with some code to achieve what you want without doing 2 xib/storyboards.

Comment: can you still support under 4.3? Like 4.0?

Comment: @LightningStryk No, you can only support 4.3 and later. And there is little reason to support 4.3 (or even 5.0). At this point you are wasting your time supporting anything earlier than iOS 5.1. Any device that can run iOS 4.3 can run iOS 5.1. And except for the iPad 1 and the 3rd gen iPod touch, any device running iOS 5.1 can be updated to iOS 6.x.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum os version is 4.3 and iPhone 5 support is mandatory. Also you should provide retina(@2x) images.

Auto layout is a feature available in ios 6 and you can use it only with deployment target 6.0.

So disable autolayout in the file inspector for all xibs and you will be able to support ios4.3