# Making my iPhone 5 app compatible with iPhone 4, iPod Touch, legacy iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new to xcode and mobile app design in general, but was able to pull together some resources and make a nice looking app optimizing for iPhone 5. However, I noticed a few problems with compatibility and am hoping someone can suggest to me a quick fix.

First, I take advantage of the entire iPhone 5 screen size, and when loaded on iPhone 4 or earlier the placement of icons is all awry. Would this be fixed by just making the entire view scrollable somehow? And if so, can someone point me in the right direction to accomplish this?

Second, I've noticed that if I am using my app while in a call (and therefore have the green notification bar at the top) it also causes misalignments for my objects. Is there a way to prevent this?

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: You need to fix your layout so the app interface scales well for multiple vertical sizes, that way you won't have any issues with larger in-call status bars and different height screens. Go into your storyboard and adjust all the alignments and constraints for your interface elements so they move correctly if the vertical height changes.

Comment: Also, making your entire app view scrollable on devices with smaller screens (pre-iPhone 5) is a **terrible** idea, and many users will hate you for it. Your app needs to be able to resize and adjust to fit everything propertly. The Ray Wenderlich tutorial link in one of the answers below is a good place to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are targeting iOS 6 you should take advantage of Auto Layout.  Here is a good tutorial to get started http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Comment: I was going to ask you to point out in the article about auto layout but as it is the whole thing and quite big I am just going to ask for a summary of what the link provides. As links can expire so this answer would become pointless. +1 for the tutorial on auto layout it was interesting.

Comment: I think in addition to this, [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12537643/352891) is quite useful; without such, Auto Layout will only hinder the backwards compat requirements.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be sure to follow this guide.

Comment: @user352891 that is also a good answer if you add it and give a good summary to why it is useful I would happily upvote.

Answer (score -2):

Add a Default-568h@2x.png launch image.
and check the all screen.

Comment: How does this solve the users issue? They are wanting iPhone 5 code to work with legacy iPhones not the other way. -1