# iTunes Connect Crash Report - UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue

Tags: objective-c, ios, crash, crash-reports

I have a crash report on iOS 5.1 that is caused by `UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue`. To my understanding this generally is due to a value being set improperly in a nib (generally something has been deleted). The crash report gives me two problems:

1. From the crash report itself I cannot see to figure out which nib is causing the crash. However I have had some review stating that the crash happens on a setting screen for some users so that is the one I am focusing on.
2. Assuming it is the Settings view, its simply a UIViewController with a table view. It has the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource. To my knowledge everything is setup correctly.

So my questions would be:

How can I confirm what nib is causing the error?
Is there anyway I can have XCode give me warning about anything that may be wrong with my nibs?

Stacktrace from the crash report is [here](http://pastebin.com/bm63xpNQ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with iOS auto layout. Similar to the issue found here:

[presentViewController: crash on iOS <6 (AutoLayout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198981/presentviewcontroller-crash-on-ios-6-autolayout)

Answer (score 0):

1. it would really help if you post the exception you got.
2. check for IBOutlets, something might be missing or set wrong (IB is not known for it's best integration with XCode)
3. check for deprecated UI elements which are inside your nib (again, IB is not known for it's compatibility with the target SDK).

Good luck!