# iOS: addConstraints: crashing app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nslayoutconstraint

## Problem

I can't seem to adopt Auto Layout into my existing project.

## Details

I was having the same issue before as this question [presentViewController: crash on iOS <6 (AutoLayout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198981/presentviewcontroller-crash-on-ios-6-autolayout) but none of the provided answers were a solution for me: I'm using all storyboard views with no xibs.  My 'Use Auto Layout' setting is already turned off and I am using nothing but iOS 6.

My view controller was initially crashing, so I set the constraints to be added with a delay and now my app crashes during any `addConstraints:` call.  Worst part is that it won't tell me why.

## Code

I will link my code, but its pretty straight forward.

```
-(void)addAllConstraints
{
    NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_memoryImage, _peopleView, _contentHolder, _commentsTableView);
    NSArray * constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[_memoryImage]-50-[_peopleView]-0-[_contentHolder]-0-[_commentsTableView]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
    NSLog(@"Views %@, Constraints %@", views, constraints);
    [_peopleView addConstraints:constraints];
    [_memoryImage addConstraints:constraints];
    [_contentHolder addConstraints:constraints];
   [_commentsTableView addConstraints:constraints];
}
```

App crashes on `_peopleView`'s call to addConstraints. Both the views and the NSLayoutConstraints are successfully created.

Any ideas?  Thank you, Happy Holidays.

EDIT:

Adding Crash logs to show that nothing useful is showing:

```
2012-12-25 10:40:13.936 -----[4955:907] Views {
"_commentsTableView" = "<UITableView: 0x1eb6be00; frame = (0 372; 320 100); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1e51ce00>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1e51cee0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>";
"_contentHolder" = "<UIView: 0x1e5c6590; frame = (0 270; 320 112); layer = <CALayer: 0x1e5c27f0>>";
"_memoryImage" = "<UIButton: 0x1e5c4aa0; frame = (0 0; 320 280); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1e5c4b60>>";
"_peopleView" = "<UIView: 0x1f0ceea0; frame = (0 230; 320 50); layer = <CALayer: 0x1f0cf790>>";

Constraints (
"NSLayoutConstraint:0x1e51a880 V:[UIButton:0x1e5c4aa0]-(50)-[UIView:0x1f0ceea0]",
"NSLayoutConstraint:0x1e5ba4e0 V:[UIView:0x1f0ceea0]-(0)-[UIView:0x1e5c6590]",
"NSLayoutConstraint:0x1e51b860 V:[UIView:0x1e5c6590]-(0)-[UITableView:0x1eb6be00]"
)


}  
   (lldb)
```

Comment: It surely gives you some information in the crash log. For starters, your spacing constants should be in brackets.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/formatLanguage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH3-SW11  Not true.  And no, there is nothing in the crash log at all.

Comment: @RobCaraway There should be at least what kind of crash occurred. Is it `SIGABRT`? `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`? Or what?

Comment: I was wrong about the brackets, sorry. I think rdelmar has your answer, but for more information when debugging constraints you might find adding an all exceptions breakpoint to be useful.

Comment: rdelmar was indeed correct. For clarification for future obverservers though, this was indeed a `SIGABRT` and Exception Break points were turned on when I was looking for solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Constraints are supposed to be added to the view that is the superview of the subviews. So, if these objects are in your main view, then you should have (and none of the other addConstraints: lines):

```
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];
```

Also, your dictionary, views, should be nil terminated (I don't know whether this is necessary or not. I've noticed in an Apple example that they didn't do this, but the function definition shows it with the nil).

Comment: You don't need to nil terminate for that bindings dictionary macro.