# Constraint in code SIGABRT Error

Tags: swift, sigabrt

[[last][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMcks.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMcks.png)
[[last][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMJGT.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMJGT.png)

I was trying to add constraint to my repeatSegment.

```
    //Repeat Segment
        repeatSegment?.setNeedsDisplay()

        repeatSegment?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let repeatSegmentConstraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: repeatSegment!, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.00, constant: 190) <<Error here
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong (quite possible), but can you use `self` as a value in `toItem`...shouldn't that be `self.view` or just `view` maybe? I mean...`self` in this case is a `UIViewController`

Comment: Can you check again, I get the new error

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code in questions. Copy and paste the code itself. I cannot read the code in the question. Same with the error message. Copy and paste text.

Comment: I thought that would provide more reasons why the error occur. Sorry

Comment: I found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14033030/4063602 (basically, add the constraint to the superview, not the child. In your case the `view` instead of the `songSlider`)

Comment: Oh thanks, yeah that's why it need to declare the item

Comment: @QuangDinhLuong I'll take the liberty of writing an answer then, OK?

Comment: Oh hey can you recheck for my new error above, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen in the comments above there was two problems here.

1. `self` could not be used as a parameter to `toItem`. In this case `self` was a `UIViewController` which caused the error. To fix this, `view` was used instead.
2. As can be seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14033030/4063602) the constraint must be added to the `superView` instead of the `child`, in this case to `view` instead of `songSlider`.