# Can't remove/hide recently added view from self.navigationcontroller.view

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, autolayout

I have a Navigationviewcontroller with a tableview in it. I am adding a UIView to self.navigationcontroller.view and constraints for Auto Layout. When I try to remove it from superview or to hide it, nothing happens.

Any ideas?

**How I create the View and Constraints**

```
-(void)doneWithTraining{

        //Create Backgroundview
        UIView *groupView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [groupView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        groupView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.7];
        groupView.tag = 999;
        groupView.alpha = 0.0;
        [self.navigationController.view addSubview:groupView];



        [self.navigationController.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:groupView
                                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                                      toItem:self.navigationController.view
                                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                                  multiplier:1.0
                                                                                    constant:0]];

        [self.navigationController.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:groupView
                                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                                      toItem:self.navigationController.view
                                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                                  multiplier:1.0
                                                                                    constant:0.0f]];

        [self.navigationController.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:groupView
                                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                                      toItem:self.navigationController.view
                                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                                  multiplier:1.0
                                                                                    constant:0.0]];
        [self.navigationController.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:groupView
                                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                                      toItem:self.navigationController.view
                                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
    }


                                                                      multiplier:1.0
                                                                                constant:0.0]];
//Animate View
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^(void) {
        groupView.alpha = 1.0;


    }];
```

**How I try to remove the View**

```
- (void)closeFinishAlert{

    UIView *grouView = [self.navigationController.view viewWithTag:999];
    grouView.hidden = YES;

    NSLog(@"Check if closeFinishAlert is called");
    //[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

**What I also tried**

This removes the view an its content, but after this there is no user interaction possible. It looks like a crash, but Xcode tells me that the app is still running.

```
- (void)closeFinishAlert{

    UIView *groupView = [self.navigationController.view viewWithTag:999];
    for (UIView *subview in groupView.subviews) {
        subview.hidden = YES;
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }

    [_groupView removeFromSuperview];

    //[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding a subview to the navigation controller? you should be adding a UIView to your viewController's view. If you tell us the nature of your view that you are trying to add and remove then we can possibly provide a better way of dealing with your situation

Comment: When I try to add anything to self.view the app always crashes due to auto layout.

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198981/presentviewcontroller-crash-on-ios-6-autolayout

you need to make sure you turn off "use auto layout" for your nibs. Then try adding your views with  `[self.view addSubview:yourView];`

Comment: Turning off auto layout is no option, I need auto layout since this app supports iPhone and iPad as well as all orientations.

Comment: And adding views to your UINavigationController is no option either. Either add your views properly and solve the crashes you get when adding your views or turn off Auto layout; let me tell you that the latter is definitely not an option when you have the former as your problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to "GoGreen" green I found a solution which works for me.

**Create Viewcontroller from ViewDidAppear**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    if (executedExercises.count == [_fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count] && self.groupView == FALSE) {

        [self performSelector:@selector(doneWithTraining) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
    }
}
```

**Header file**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *groupView;
```

**Creating the Viewcrontroller and its content**

```
-(void)doneWithTraining{
         _groupView = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:_groupView animated:YES completion:nil];
        _groupView.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    //SubTitle
    UILabel *subTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [subTitleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:18.0]];
    subTitleLabel.textColor = [BackgroundLayer gray];
    [subTitleLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    subTitleLabel.numberOfLines = 5;
    subTitleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    subTitleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [_groupView.view addSubview:subTitleLabel];
    subTitleLabel.text = subTitleText;



    [_groupView.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subTitleLabel
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual
                                                                   toItem:_groupView.view
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                               multiplier:0.0
                                                                 constant:300.0f]];

    [_groupView.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subTitleLabel
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:_groupView.view
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                               multiplier:0.0
                                                                 constant:140]];

    [_groupView.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subTitleLabel
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:_groupView.view
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                               multiplier:1.0
                                                                 constant:0.0]];

    [_groupView.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subTitleLabel
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:_groupView.view
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                               multiplier:1.0
                                                                 constant:0.0]];}
```

**Removing ViewController**

```
- (void)closeFinishAlert{    
    [_groupView dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually just presenting a `view` which you will remove for sure later on,
 then its better to create a `ViewController` class for your `view` and present it modally using :

```
[self presentViewController:yourViewControllerObject animated:NO completion:nil];
```

you can later on remove this `view` using:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

hope this helps !

Comment: Bam! This could be the solution. I will try this.

Comment: I tried it, but I am getting the following error: NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: Constraint items must each be an instance of UIView or subclass'

Is there a specific way to add auto layout constraints on a programmatically created view?