# NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException with ContainerView

Tags: ios5, storyboard, ios6, segue

Using a ContainerView with an embed seque
I'm getting this:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named UIStoryboardEmbedSegueTemplate'

My searches didn't provide a lot, so:
Does this mean
"Sorry, only on iOS6" ?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. My program run on IOS6. Which means that we must have used some feature that's IOS6 only. Don't know what.

Comment: once go through this link it may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085859/how-can-i-fix-nsinvalidunarchiveoperationexception

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this really seems to be a "iOS 6 only"-feature. I did not see it in iOS 5 either... But didn't find it in the Docs so far.

Comment: Ty, the state of documentation is horrible, there.

Comment: Had the same problem. You can that it is not supporting this feature prior 6.0 if you select the story board file and change und Document Versioning die Deployment to iOS 5.1. You get immediatyl an error message stating that "Embed segues are not available on iOS 5.1 and prior."