# Debugging strategies when UITableView's cells don't load?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, subview

I am trying to embed a UITableView into my ViewController's main UIView that is 75% the width of the screen. Ideally this UITableView would also be embedded into a Navigation Controller. Also, it seems I cannot use UIContainerViews with iOS 5 because I encounter the error "Could not instantiate class named UIStoryboardEmbedSegueTemplate" (cf. [NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException with ContainerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868255/nsinvalidunarchiveoperationexception-with-containerview)).

To do this, I have created a UIView within my ViewController's main UIView that is 75% the width of the screen. Within that UIView I have placed a UINavigationBar and a UITableView. I instantiate the UITableViewController in the ViewController's `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil` function. Once instantiated, I connect my ViewController's UITableView to the UITableViewController's UITableView via `self.tableViewController.tableView = self.tableView`.

Everything seems to work alright, except that my UITableView isn't showing any cells, even if I preload it with data.

What additional data may I provide to help diagnose the problem? I of course don't receive any error message, and the datasource does indeed receive the data and I call `[self.tableView reloadData]` after the datasource is updated.

**UPDATE 1**

[image: Chrome for iOS]

Ultimately this is the kind of behavior I would like, except that instead of multiple web views I would like multiple table views each embedded in its own navigation controller. I'm guessing that Chrome for iOS just takes a screenshot (?) of the webpage since interaction is not enabled when scrolling through tabs, but how would you do this if you wanted to preserve interaction?

**UPDATE 2**

The particular line seems to be `CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]` where `static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"New Cell"` (and the appropriate prototype UITableViewCell is defined such in IB). However, the code doesn't seem to crash on this line; instead, a breakpoint seems to be initiated (`Thread 1: Breakpoint 1.1`) that I did not designate. In addition, this only happens when testing on my iOS device. Everything works fine when testing via the iOS simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello: The ultimate answer to my particular problem related to how iOS 5 v. iOS 6 handles autolayout, in particular with regard to UITableViewCells ("Autoresize subviews"); cf., [What are some reasons why custom UITableViewCells might work in iOS 6 but not iOS 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059985/what-are-some-reasons-why-custom-uitableviewcells-might-work-in-ios-6-but-not-io)

Since this particular question is vague and the "answer" doesn't relate to what I thought the problem was, should I vote to delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Your datasource methods need to be implemented in your `tableViewController` (which it seems you did not do). You would have to set the `datasource` property of your tableViewController to `self` and implement the methods in your original view controller (i.e. `self`). Also, you would have to add the `<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>` protocols in the @interface declaration.

Is it not easier to got the standard route and subclass `UITableViewController` to override the datasource methods?

Comment: I've done all of that, except that I delegated my dataSource out to the main ViewController, since I figured that was the active view controller and also the controller receiving relevant touch events, e.g., I've added a plus UIBarButtonItem for adding new entries to the list. Does the dataSource have to be internal?

Comment: Should I just copy-past my entire code? StackOverflow doesn't seemed to be designed for doing that (at least well).

Comment: Indeed you should not code-dump. Put in break points and log statements - narrow down the problem and post that code.